# How to deal with ' and " characters in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match certain phrases using this regex

```
String k = "{'hello','hi'}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{)(((([A-Za-z0-9_()\'\"\\.\\+\\-\\*/])+((,)?([A-Za-z0-9_()\\+\\-\\*/]))*)|(\\w)))?(\\})");


Matcher match = pattern.matcher(k);
System.out.println(match.matches());
```

It work fine with all the chars that I specifies which means it matches `{1,2}` or `{1+3,method()}` and so on....
only when I get string with `"` char or `'` like  `"{"hello","hi"}"` inside it seems that the regex doesn't identify this chars.

Is there a special way to catch them?

Answer (score 2):

You can escape characters with \ example \' = ' and \" = "

I would rather use [^}] and [^,], this gets everything except that specific character.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue may have been with your regex, not specifically the ' and " characters. The second block for containing more fields was missing a few characters (specifically the ' and " characters), and so it was not catching 'hi' as valid. You are handling these characters correctly by including a "\" in front of them to escape them (giving you \' and \").

I've tested the following regex with your example ({'hello','hi'}), and it was picking up the text correctly.

```
({)(((([A-Za-z0-9_()\'\"\\.\\+\\-\\*/])+((,)?([A-Za-z0-9_()\'\"\\.\\+\\-\\*/]))*)|(\\w)))?(})
```

If you are in need of any sort of help with regex, or would like an easier way to test and debug your regex, I would suggest the website [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/). It is a great visual tool to use whenever you are doing anything with regex. I used this tool for checking your initial regex to find which part of the regex was not being picked up, and then to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're always trying to snag tuples within curly braces, your regex can be simplified quite a bit:

```
String k = "{'hello','hi'}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*),(.*)\\}");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(k);
System.out.println(match.matches());
System.out.println(match.group(1));
System.out.println(match.group(2));
```

Prints:

```
true
'hello'
'hi'
```

Additionally, since Java's regex parser presumably recognizes that the leading '{' and trailing '}' are not a part of a regex interval specifier, they would not be treated as metacharacters.  Therefore, your backslashes could be removed and the regex could be trimmed down to:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("{(.*),(.*)}");
```